# Custom Grid, how to adjust bootstrap to it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

A customer has handle me very specific measures for a custom grid, not 100% sure how to handle it. Here are the measures:

```
**Width: 320px** 
Sides: (26px) (2 sides)
Column:  (52px) (4 columns)
Gutter:  (20px) (3 gutters)

**Width: 768px**
Sides: (76px)  (2 sides)
Column:  (33px) (12 columns)
Gutter:  (20px) (11 gutters)

**Width: 1024px** 
Sides: (72px)  (2 sides)
Column:  (55px) (12 columns)
Gutter:  (20px) (11 gutters)

**Width: 1280px**
Sides: (74px)  (2 sides)
Column:  (76px) (12 columns)
Gutter:  (20px) (11 gutters)
```

I have been searching and found that Bootstrap 4 has option to customize its grid:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#columns-and-gutters

I see I can customize gutter:

```
$grid-gutter-widths: (
  xs: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  sm: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  md: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  lg: $grid-gutter-width-base,
  xl: $grid-gutter-width-base
)
```

Also width:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  sm: 480px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 420px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px
);
```

I do not see a way to customize columns, any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `.col-3` 4 times for 4 columns? You still get 3 "gutters". Same effect, easier to do and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can change number of columns in Bootstrap by changing [`$grid-columns`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/2e5f1e22860a892f5abdbb65abc14172e0129c1a/scss/_variables.scss#L173) value. You don't need to change it, though.

Let's say you leave default value of `$grid-columns: 12`. In order to have 4 columns on smaller screen, just use `col-3` 4 times. You still get 3 "gutters" between those columns. For larger screens you can use `.col-md-1` 12 times and you get 12 columns. It's the way to do it in Bootstrap.

You cannot set different amount of columns for different screen sizes in Bootstrap. So for example it's not possible that both `.col-3` (max 3 columns) and `col-md-12` (max 12 columns) would cover 100% of row width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have worked only with compiled bootstrap (I think that is its name), how can I configure the columns? is it through Saas? how can I do it?. Also if you see in my question, it has specific measures, how can I configure "sides" in bootstrap (not sure how is called in bootstrap the padding of the container)?. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, through the Sass. You can modify all these Bootstrap Sass variables if you get [source files](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#source-files). Then of course you need to compile all that sass into css at the end by yourself.